# Finder pattern for detecting image alignment markers

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection, omr

I am looking for an algorithm that can detect image alignment markers similar to the way QR codes use square markers on 3 corners to align and orient. I intend to use this solution to perform image normalization within the boundaries of the markers.

Comment: Cool - please show sample images and your code so far. Also tell us a bit about your environment and which packages you work with.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you need a minimum reputation before you can post images.  But any code you have so far will help.

Comment: So far the project is in exploratory phase so there is no code so far. I am looking for a library or omr algorithm (like Hough's transform) that can do the trick. The application will be written in JavaScript eventually.

Comment: You first need to design the markers so that the are easy to distinguish from other features and to detect.